# Angular cli prod mobile

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I recognised that my application is not working correctly on mobile devices. Some data from database is missing and some functionality is not working. Locally and on my server with my notebook or desktop computer it is working but not with mobile devices. Is Angular CLI not supporting mobile devices? I am using --prod --aot for compiling and I thought this would work? What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mobile flag is disabled right now, seems they are working out some kinks.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#support-for-offline-applications